# WordPress rewrite old URL to new one

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have WordPress installed and I have some old URls indexed, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/article-title.html
```

They were working before, but now I changed my URl structure so if I type in Web browser:

```
http://www.example.com/article-title/
```

The new one is working but if I visit my old URL with .html, it gives me error 404.

Is there a way for rewrite those old to new one?

Maybe 301 SEO redirect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go into your .htaccess on your server and at the top of the file you can add something like this

```
Redirect 301 /article-title.html http://www.example.com/article-title/
```

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm!